# What is the difference between $\in$, $\subseteq$, and $\subset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I struggle to understand what the difference is between $\in$, $\subseteq$, $\subset$ and how they interact with different types of sets.

For example say I have two sets,
$$A = \{ \text{red}, \text{green}, \text{blue}, \text{yellow} \}$$
and
$$B = \{\text{blue}, \text{yellow}\}.$$

If I want to say "*Yellow is inside of $B$"* I think $\text{yellow} \in B$ is a correct way to do it.

But what if I want "*$B$ is inside of $A$*", is $B \in A$ still correct?

And what if I start using power sets? Are $B \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $\mathcal{P}(B) \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ correct, or should I use another operator?

Comment: $B\in A$ would imply that $B$ is an element of $A$, for instance if $A=\{ \{blue,yellow\}, red, green, blue, yellow\}$. But this is not the case in the example in the question.

Comment: Writing $B\subseteq A$ means that for every $b\in B$, $b\in A$. In the example that you give it means that $blue\in A$ and $yellow \in A$ which is true. $B\subset A$ usually (but not always) means that $B\subseteq A$, but $B\not = A$.

Comment: For the most part, if you see $B \subset A$ or $B \subseteq A$, they both mean that "every element of B is an element of A." Unless the author explicitly says so, I find it overwhelmingly more common that neither notation excludes the possibility that the two sets are equal. To denote a proper subset, and avoid ambiguity, its best practice to write $B \subsetneq A$

Comment: I agree that most often $\subset$ means the same thing as $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\in B$ means that $A$ is an element of $B$. For example $2 \in \{1,2,3\}$, $4\in \mathbb N$, but we can also do that with sets, for example, $\{1\}\in\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$. In this case, $B$ is always a set, and $A$ can be a number, a word, a set, etc...

when you write: $A\subseteq B$, both $A$ and $B$ are sets. This means that every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$. for example: $\{2\}\subseteq\{1,2,3\}$, but also $\{1,2\}\subseteq\{1,2,3\}$.

the diference between $\subseteq$ and $\subset$, is that, when we say $A\subseteq B$, this means that every element of $A$ is in $B$, or $A=B$ (it's the same when you write $x\leq y$. this means that $x$ is less than $y$, or $x=y$). When you write $A\subset B$, you are saying that every element of $A$ is in $B$, but $A$ is not equal to $B$ (just like when you right $x<y$).

Answering some of your specific questions: $B\in \mathcal P(A)$ means that $B$ is in the set, of all subsets of $A$, thus $B\subseteq A$.

$\mathcal P(B)\in \mathcal P(A)$ is a bit more tecnical. In general $\mathcal P(B)\in \mathcal P(A)$ is not correct, but $\mathcal P(B)\subseteq \mathcal P(A)$ is true if $B\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother using the "i" word. As you have plainly demonstrated, it is ambiguous.

Instead, use solely the mathematical terminology:

- *Yellow is an element of $B$* to say Yellow$\in B$,
- *$B$ is a subset of $A$* to say $B \subseteq A$.

Comment: Further to these suggestions, one can also say $A$ _includes_ ($\supseteq$) $B$, which _owns_ ($\owns$) yellow.

Answer (score 0):

For subsets there are two different systems of notation...

$\bullet\;$  $A \subset B$ for "$A$ is a subset of $B$" $\quad$ and $\qquad A \subsetneq B$ for "$A$ is a proper subset of $B$"

or

$\bullet\;$  $A \subseteq B$ for "$A$ is a subset of $B$" $\quad$ and $\qquad A \subset B$ for "$A$ is a proper subset of $B$"